# Change the first column of the matrix from another specified matrix

Tags: python

I have 2 matrices

```
x = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
y = [0,2,4]
```

and i want to change each first element from each row of matrix x using each element from matrix y so the end result would be

```
x = [[0,2,3],
     [2,5,6],
     [4,8,9]]
```

i have tried this code

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [0,2,4]
for i in range (len(x)):
    x[i][0] = y[0][i]

print (x)
```

but it only returns "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

are there any ways to fix this and how do you expand this so that it's appliable to any n*n matrix?

Comment: Hint: What is `y[0]` in the loop doing and why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Change `x[i][0] = y[0][i]` to `x[i][0] = y[i]`.

Another way to do this with fewer indices:

```py
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
y = [0, 2, 4]

for x_row, y_int in zip(x, y):
    x_row[0] = y_int

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have matrices. `x` is a `list` of `lists` and `y` is a `list`. They can *represent* matrices/vectors/etc., but those are ultimately mathematical abstractions, which can be implemented in code in different ways.

The first way to do it, maintaining the structure of your code, requires taking note of the above fact: as `y` is a `list` containing `ints`, `y[0][i]` will clearly not work, since `y[0]` will always be an `int`, and you cannot further apply the subscript operator to `ints`.

Accordingly, this will work:

```
for i in range (len(x)):
    x[i][0] = y[i]
```

That said, that is not the only way to do it. If you desired a more functional approach, you could do something like this `list` comprehension:

```
[[y_value, *x_value[1:]] for x_value, y_value in zip(x, y)]
```

This gives the same result, but approaches the problem in a more abstract way: the new `list` will itself contain `lists` where the first element comes from `y` and the rest from `x`. Understanding this, we can instead *compose* an inner list following this pattern.

`zip` creates an `iterator` of pairs of values from `x` and `y`. Using this iterator, each value from `y` can be positioned before each value from `x` in a `list`.  Lastly, since `x_value` is a `list`, it must be *unpacked* so we get, for example, `[0, 2, 4]` instead of `[0, [2, 4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you would typically avoid using indexes when possible.  Since a "matrix" is actually a list of lists, going through rows returns lists which are object references that you can manipulate directly:

```
for row,value in zip(x,y): row[0] = value
```